Controlable animation using Matplotlib?
We can create gifs from plots generated in Python, usually through a loop where you save each image and then you animate them, creating a gif by compiling the images one after the other. Is there any way to do so but without saving the images?
The same way I use plt.show() to see the plots I want to do that for the gif. And when I can check the compilation of images, I want to be able to go through them by pressing the arrow keys. Like if it were a book or a document.
I haven't been able to find a solution for this or know if it's even possible.
Thank you for your time.

Something like this? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/pause_resume.html

Or this? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/buttons.html#sphx-glr-gallery-widgets-buttons-py

No, I need more control on the animation. To be able to go through frame by frame at my desire. So I can spend time with one frame, then go back 5 frames and then play the whole thing. And then to configure all that to keyboard arrows, which I don't know if it's possible. Thanks for the answer @RuthC
